# Python - Alternative for using numpy array as key in dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I'm pretty new to Python numpy. I attempted to use the numpy array as the key in the dictionary in one of my functions and then was told by the Python interpreter that the numpy array is not hashable. I've just found out that one way to work this issue around is to use `repr()` function to convert a numpy array to a string but it seems very expensive. Is there any better way to achieve the same effect?

Update: I could create a new class to contain the numpy array, which seems to be the right way to achieve what I want. Just wondering if there is any better method.

update 2: Using a class to contain data in the array and then override `__hash__` function is acceptable, however, I'd prefer the solution provided by @hpaulj. Converting the `array/list` to a `tuple` fits my need in a better way as it does not require an additional class.

Comment: What are you doing that you want to use a numpy array (in whatever form it is) as a dictionary key?

Comment: You may use the data in numpy array to create a `hash` which could be used as a key for dictionary.

Comment: @JonClements I need a dictionary to map a 1-d vector to a set of points

Comment: @ZdaR Will try that. Cheers

Comment: Try `tuple(A.tolist())`.  For a 1d array this conversion is straight forward.

Comment: @hpaulj I've already used a class to contain my array but your advice works flawlessly ! Thank you sir.Would u mind put this comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to quickly store a `numpy.ndarray` as a key in a dictionary, a fast option is to use [ndarray.tobytes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html)() which will return a raw python `bytes` string which is immutable

```
my_array = numpy.arange(4).reshape((2,2))
my_dict = {}
my_dict[my_array.tobytes()] = None
```

Comment: +2 for the efficiency in both the key creation process and the key size.

Comment: This is great. Both simple and efficient.

Comment: Love this. Exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: You have to be careful with `hash(array.data.tobytes())` when the arrays are of different shape. For example, `np.zeros((2, 1))` and `np.zeros((1, 2))` have the same bytes.

Answer (score 13):

After done some researches and reading through all comments. I think I've known the answer to my own question so I'd just write them down.

1. Write a class to contain the data in the `array` and then override `__hash__` function to amend the way how it is **hashed** as mentioned by [ZdaR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3051961/zdar)
2. Convert this `array` to a `tuple`, which makes the list **hashable** instantaneously.Thanks to [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)

I'd prefer method No.2 because it fits my need better, as well as simpler. However, using a class might bring some additional benefits so it could also be useful.

Comment: I think its better if you add a code snippet for future readers

Answer (score -3):

I just ran into that issue and there's a very simple solution to it using list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

dict = {'key1':1, 'key2':2}
my_array = np.array(['key1', 'key2'])

result = np.array( [dict[element] for element in my_array] )
print(result)
```

The result should be:

```
[1 2]
```

I don't know how efficient this is but seems like a very practical and straight-forward solution, no conversions or new classes needed :)

Comment: This is unrelated to the question. The keys in your dictionary are just strings (`'key1'`, `'key2'`)