# add [key,value] to python dictionary in a loop

Tags: python, dictionary, point-clouds

I am new to python and I am trying to index a bunch of pcd files(each file is essentially an n*3 array) by matching them with their classtype. certain file is class 1, 2, 3 and so on. WHen i try to run it I am getting an `unhashable numpy.ndarray`error. Since I have a row of files that I need to load and index, how should I proceed?

```css
path= glob.glob("path/to/pcd/folder/*.pcd")
data_dict=dict()
for i in range(len(list(path):
    currentPath = path[i]
    classtype=currentPath[-5:]
    classtype=classtype[0]
    p = pcl.load(path[i])
    a = np.asarray(p)
    data_dict[a]=classtype
```

Comment: One problem is that you have the dict lookup backward. In line three you have `”Object”:a` which is to say the key is obeject and the value is a. If you want to get a you should do `dict[“Object”]` rather than `dict[a]`

Comment: You should review the dict [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Hey @K.Dackow, I tried your solution and now my loop is going through iterations but it is overwriting the previous array. The relationship I am looking to establish in my dictionary is a:classtype. Shall I declare it differently?

Comment: What do you mean a:classtype? Right now classtype is just a string so it does not actually represent the type of the object, it is literally just classtype. But yes, if you want to dictionary to map a to classtype then switch the order of them in the declaration

Comment: But what is your objective? Could you clarify what you want the dict to do? Do you want each element in the input array to be an element in the dictionary mapping to its classtype?

Comment: Also, you shouldn’t name your dictionary dict, because it overrides the built in dict functionality.

Comment: classtype is an int type I am also getting from the files. each file has its own classtype and I want to map one entire pointcloud to one classtype.

Comment: Okay. So the dictionary you want to be able to lookup a PCL and get a classtype, or do you want to lookup a classtype and get a PCL?

Comment: look up a pcl and get a classtype

Comment: And it appears you’re typing the dictionary elements, (i.e. it seems you’re saying a is type Object and classtype is type Label, a la some other Programming Language’s syntaxes) is that a correct assessment? If so, you should know *python does not take type annotations*!

Comment: I’ll put an answer below

Comment: That would be correct. As I mentioned in my post I am fairly new to python. Basically what I want to do is when I look up into a dictionary: all pointclouds stored under the group 'Object' and their corresponding classtype stored under 'Label'. How can I achieve this? Is `append` after every iteration the solution?

Comment: I’d highly recommend reviewing the documentation linked above.

Comment: So my answer below should help with that! However, for additional clarity, I can explain what the code above does. In python, a dict declared as follows: `d = {‘this’: ‘that’}` would mean that if you lookup this (`d[‘this’]`) you’ll get ‘that’ outputted

Comment: ah okay this helps me understand dicts in python to a certain extent I will try to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

To put all PCLs in a dictionary so that you can look up their corresponding Classtypes, you need to do something like this:

```
my_dict = dict() # declaring empty dictionary
for point_cloud in pcl_list:
    my_dict[point_cloud] = classtype #somewhere in the loop you need to set what classtype is for each specific point_cloud
```

Now you can do this:

```
>> my_dict[some_pcl]
<the corresponding classtype>
```

Comment: I think review of the documentation will help me understand it much better. I tried your code but it still gave me the `unhashable numpy.ndarray`error.

Comment: What line is throwing that error? My code isn’t full code and will not work, because i don’t know exactly the data structures you are working with. However, it conceptually shows how to iterate through something to put them in a dictionary

Comment: And what is causing the error? What line or object? Could you post more of your code in the question?

Comment: I have added the entire code. The error is in the last line of the code. Hope it helps !

Comment: Rename dict to something else. You are overriding the builtin dictionary methods by naming a variable dict! I don’t know if that will fix the problem completely, but it does need to be changed

Comment: made the changes but the error is still the same. `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: So you actually can’t use a numpy array as the key for a dict. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39674863/10089715) for help with avoiding that.

Comment: After some research I figured out the solution to my problem. Since ultimately I need to save this dictionary into an hdf5 file, I can create 2 datasets, namely 'data' and 'label' and store values in them. That has given me a new problem but the old one has been solved.