# how to solve the TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'?

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, scipy, pyspark, numpy-ndarray

`print (embed.take(1))` return the following:

```
[(u'text', array([-0.31921682, -0.20686883,  0.01824462,  0.13350081,  0.01187224,
        0.22116834, -0.287487  , -0.11509234,  0.01763669,  0.06377559,
        0.2989474 ,  0.41020724, -0.22037283,  0.45994595, -0.12425458,
       -0.20881261,  0.06872807,  0.53261876,  0.45528108,  0.3245842 ,
        0.09092806,  0.17639753, -0.47674257, -0.00098801, -0.12842408,
       -0.2413709 ,  0.38194713, -0.11250313, -0.15904745,  0.16058864,
       -0.33080024,  0.37156585,  0.01329294,  0.36711624,  0.1973844 ,
       -0.18771271,  0.08853641,  0.23573542,  0.09280699, -0.07244137,
        0.09726012, -0.28807876,  0.01709639,  0.375758  ,  0.4611828 ,
        0.02307661,  0.3119973 , -0.5212216 ,  0.230173  , -0.09128311,
        0.2713826 , -0.2568359 , -0.11232495,  0.00200466,  0.09583885,
       -0.25420523, -0.10021619, -0.19341935, -0.22922793,  0.0212901 ,
        0.20808727,  0.32417038,  0.03864996,  0.2969149 , -0.03171158,
        0.45413095,  0.6309765 ,  0.28096622, -0.45515797,  0.28787974,
       -0.5809179 , -0.09877653,  0.24814974, -0.35588014,  0.42792156,
        0.21451631, -0.1350529 ,  0.37952444, -0.00165558,  0.384076  ,
        0.1413526 ,  0.08866125, -0.10355992,  0.25019792, -0.00393839,
        0.5695221 , -0.12449711,  0.00210058,  0.07765691,  0.3281926 ,
       -0.08014766,  0.20689923, -0.22970992,  0.07591247, -0.15799475,
       -0.22765721, -0.1927638 , -0.15355097,  0.09073654, -0.04624737,
       -0.01643844, -0.8464762 ,  0.08931787,  0.5332598 ,  0.2911471 ,
        0.3791839 , -0.303577  , -0.22905344, -0.21888404, -0.1810556 ,
       -0.019493  ,  0.1367392 ,  0.2187451 ,  0.04935849,  0.14806354,
       -0.00551599, -0.05861316,  0.26915333, -0.3377117 ,  0.00114926,
       -0.08245742,  0.4929164 ,  0.06329145,  0.88905925,  0.25238925,
       -0.33230686,  0.19560733,  0.4172665 ,  0.02552557,  0.26976195,
        0.26783204, -0.25621846,  0.1972084 , -0.3187281 ,  0.04309576,
        0.5668932 , -0.20068711, -0.55052537,  0.38765076,  0.4864744 ,
        0.1130944 , -0.01685749,  0.2522309 ,  0.35446006, -0.09084648,
        0.24245648,  0.06625048,  0.32369784, -0.06834482, -0.43762162,
        0.5748935 , -0.3647702 ,  0.35806394, -0.1582715 ,  0.0772159 ,
       -0.16100545,  0.4267    , -0.1307025 , -0.03227446,  0.10494301,
       -0.05289922,  0.7097728 , -0.17166416, -0.054304  ,  0.12740278,
       -0.14317441, -0.26385677, -0.22849232,  0.10305541, -0.04086439,
       -0.46178675, -0.09216189, -0.76668286, -0.09225449, -0.2168125 ,
        0.12703866,  0.05073327,  0.04017496, -0.24126993,  0.06369572,
       -0.09168304, -0.40669888,  0.28603286, -0.04988515,  0.05513516,
        0.7806739 , -0.02534869,  0.00973589,  0.33947662,  0.24699458,
        0.42974108, -0.19158548,  0.07973159,  0.30443648,  0.01040802,
        0.1698588 ,  0.06705329,  0.03138978, -0.5304623 ,  0.1360791 ,
        0.24522378,  0.12584817, -0.14219321,  0.19166584,  0.2226152 ,
        0.07703363,  0.23977087,  0.11122001,  0.1861035 ,  0.37293455,
        0.33047304, -0.00121733,  0.5897423 , -0.06080131, -0.05202375,
        0.10317306, -0.04354465, -0.31621787,  0.35597408,  0.3476911 ,
        0.19293919, -0.02774811, -0.2739977 , -0.08927495,  0.04805851,
       -0.17200205, -0.7588404 , -0.0615377 ,  0.22575249, -0.09135661,
        0.05711236,  0.04755763, -0.22369057, -0.17867683, -0.5001432 ,
       -0.50440204,  0.09518195,  0.21083611,  0.1761034 , -0.12429572,
       -0.39988747,  0.61002195,  0.4314368 ,  0.02579845, -0.28676844,
       -0.03552085,  0.21395397,  0.075849  , -0.21982886, -0.39733076,
        0.17018917,  0.0251913 ,  0.14543247,  0.2262631 , -0.05759874,
       -0.18585657,  0.3211592 , -0.272339  , -0.22289205, -0.31557533,
        0.27803165,  0.22905917, -0.15953094, -0.10018265, -0.32501385,
        0.3319722 , -0.5288052 , -0.18201298,  0.08485821, -0.3703766 ,
        0.21344219, -0.13149662,  0.21560058,  0.08420809,  0.15680231,
        0.22140822,  0.24218608,  0.40488818, -0.00483301, -0.34549713,
        0.4376315 ,  0.53999686,  0.5157788 , -0.14618067,  0.15518756,
       -0.29715803,  0.3193897 ,  0.08780982, -0.08137056, -0.01085411,
        0.17661236,  0.03506121, -0.030442  , -0.04898388,  0.36918342,
       -0.07420906,  0.24415983, -0.02784878,  0.11730439,  0.24948044],
      dtype=float32))]
```

and `print(type(embed))` prints: `<class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'>`.

Th excption is thrown when I execute the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/project/6008168/tamouze/testSparkCedar.py", line 390, in 
>       print(embed1.distinct().count())   File "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py",
>   line 1056, in count   File
>   "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py",
>   line 1047, in sum   File
>   "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py",
>   line 921, in fold   File
>   "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py",
>   line 824, in collect   File
>   "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1160, in **call**   File
>   "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 320, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 3 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0
>   in stage 1.0 (TID 4, localhost, executor driver):
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 229, in main
>       process()   File "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 224, in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)   File
>   "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py",
>   line 2438, in pipeline_func   File
>   "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py",
>   line 2438, in pipeline_func   File
>   "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py",
>   line 362, in func   File
>   "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py",
>   line 1857, in combineLocally   File
>   "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/spark/2.3.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py",
>   line 238, in mergeValues
>       d[k] = comb(d[k], v) if k in d else creator(v) TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

I get the embed as following:

```
inputInvertedIndexEmbedding = inputRawEmbed.flatMap(lambda (url, document): [(url, word) for word in document.lower().split()]).map(lambda (url, word): (word,  Loader(modelpath).map(word)))
```

where loader is :

```
    import gensim
    from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText as FT_gensim
    import numpy as np

        class Loader(object):
            cache = {}
            emb_d

ic = {}
        count = 0
        def __init__(self, filename):
            #print("\n|-------------------------------------|")
            #print ("Welcome to Loader class in python")
            #print("\n|-------------------------------------|")
            self.fn = filename

        @property
        def fasttext(self):
            #if Loader.count == 1:
                #print("already loaded")
            if self.fn not in Loader.cache:
                Loader.cache[self.fn] =  FT_gensim.load_fasttext_format(self.fn)
                print ("==================================================================")
                Loader.count = Loader.count + 1
                print("**********************The class Loader is loded for the {} times ******************".format(Loader.count))
                print ("==================================================================")

            return Loader.cache[self.fn]


        def map(self, word):
            if word not in self.fasttext:
                Loader.emb_dic[word] = np.random.uniform(low = 0.0, high = 1.0, size = 300)
                return Loader.emb_dic[word]
            return self.fasttext[word]
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use the array as a dictionary key. Hard to tell with that data dump and no code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist i added the code. can you please check and spot where is my mistake

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Alternative for using numpy array as key in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674863/python-alternative-for-using-numpy-array-as-key-in-dictionary)

Comment: Please format the traceback as code instead of a quote. The line breaks area important for legibility.

Comment: @MadPhysicist i can doing because the post become all as code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist can you please help m solving the problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540970/how-we-can-execute-a-code-once-per-each-executor-not-per-partition/54611496#54611496

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that Pyspark doesn't know what to do with numpy arrays when it comes to typing them since numpy has their own types as opposed to Python's float/double - I see this error usually when doing something similar in a dataframe. If you return `self.fasttext[word].tolist()` and convert any other numpy types to base python types prior to returning them it should resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by :

```
inputInvertedIndexEmbedding= inputRawEmbed.flatMap(lambda (url, document): [(url, word) for word in document.lower().split()]).map(lambda (url, word): (word, tuple(Loader(modelpath).map(word))))
```