# how to use NumPy array as a key in dict - Python

Tags: numpy, dictionary, hashable

I would like to use NumPy arrays as keys where each key will have a set of NumPy arrays as a value. I am wondering what is the most efficient way of doing this operation (i..e, inserting, searching).

```
my_keys = np.random.rand(5, 2)
my_keys 
array([[0.05152605, 0.12405425],
       [0.44344738, 0.87479441],
       [0.39542315, 0.2788064 ],
       [0.470308  , 0.73640885],
       [0.58107681, 0.42968256]])
my_values =  np.random.rand(10, 2)
my_values 
array([[0.96544233, 0.38396357],
       [0.55453457, 0.83432399],
       [0.8736443 , 0.0506048 ],
       [0.98617731, 0.41264541],
       [0.76856053, 0.23441502],
       [0.06770689, 0.27087991],
       [0.29328327, 0.57327051],
       [0.31798657, 0.11341894],
       [0.76256025, 0.08786568],
       [0.71370639, 0.30637008]])
```

Suppose my first key is `[0.05152605, 0.12405425]`, I want the first two rows of `my_values` to be the value as `[[0.96544233, 0.38396357],[0.55453457, 0.83432399]]`

There is a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674863/python-alternative-for-using-numpy-array-as-key-in-dictionary) for a similar question, but there is no code snippet. For example, I've tried what is offered as

```
my_array = numpy.arange(4).reshape((2,2))
my_dict = {}
my_dict[my_array.tobytes()] = None
```

however, it did not work for me.

Comment: What's the point to doing this, especially if the arrays are float?  Even if you succeed in converting the array to something hashable, generating that 'key' again from scratch may be difficult.  Usually we recommend using `np.isclose` (or `allclose`) when comparing float arrays, due to the inherent precision limits of floats.  Even if 2 arrays are `allclose`, they could produce different `tobytes` strings and dict keys.

Comment: Could you share a small code snippet showing what you recommend? I was also asking what could be the most efficient way to do this operation. I have vectors of floats each of which is associated with several ````arrays````. I thought that using ````dict```` would be the way to go.

Comment: I can't suggest an alternative without knowing something about this "association".  What's the source of these arrays (keys and values).  How will you create/choose keys after you've create the dict.  It's one thing to write `adict['foobar']`, quite another to use `adict[list(adict.keys)[3]]` to access the array corresponding to the 4th key vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip the keys and a reshaped view of your values, then construct a *dict* by hashing the keys:

```
>>> d = {k.tobytes(): v for k, v in zip(my_keys, my_values.reshape(5,2,2))}
{b'\x0f4U\xe6\x9cN\xd9?v\x97z\xcc\xf6\xd7\xd1?': 
     array([[0.76856053, 0.23441502], [0.06770689, 0.27087991]]),
 b'1\xbcHW\x9fa\xaa?\xe6\x07\xae\xf2\x04\xc2\xbf?': 
     array([[0.96544233, 0.38396357], [0.55453457, 0.83432399]]),
 b'[3\xa6\x1eqa\xdc?B\x8e\xb5\xd8P\xfe\xeb?': 
     array([[0.8736443 , 0.0506048 ], [0.98617731, 0.41264541]]),
 b'\x89?\xedd.\x98\xe2?\xc3#\xb7G\xeb\x7f\xdb?': 
     array([[0.76256025, 0.08786568], [0.71370639, 0.30637008]]),
 b'\xcd\x04\xc3\xb9\x86\x19\xde?\xdf\x84\xe7J\xa9\x90\xe7?': 
     array([[0.29328327, 0.57327051], [0.31798657, 0.11341894]])}
```

Then, given a key `k`, you can query the *dictionnary*:

```
>>> k = my_keys[2]
>>> d[k.tobytes()]
array([[0.76856053, 0.23441502],
       [0.06770689, 0.27087991]])
```